# how to read all users meetings in c#

Tags: c#, exchange-server

i have an application where i am asked to read all users meetings, i searched about this but there is no clear articles

- i need to read all users meetings using c#
- how can i give a specific user access to all users meetings "calendar items" in exchange server

i found the below code i tried but it always return unauthorized

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
service.TraceEnabled = true;

service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(
   "user",
   "password",
   "domain.com");

service.AutodiscoverUrl("user@domain.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

var appointmentsList = service.FindAppointments(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, calendarView);
```

the above code returns Request error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: And are you in fact authorized to access that server? What if the error message is actually correct and you are in fact not authorized?

Comment: i found the issue the AutodiscoverUrl redirect to wrong url. so i use this instead service.Url = new Uri("myurl"); and its working now

Comment: So please put an answer in the space provided below so people who follow after you can learn from your experience. That's the idea with this site.

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue the AutodiscoverUrl redirect to wrong url. so i use this instead service.Url = new Uri("myurl"); and its working now